# my guessing game is not working and i don´t know why

Tags: c#

I'm working on a guessing game that I need to improve for school, and I need to make it so that my game can make more rounds. But I hav a problem, the program doesn´t want to quit, it only starts a new round even if I "make the quit command".
The problem now is that my game doesn´t even want to start and I have no idea why. I have tried so many things to try to fix it and nothing works and I need to make it to a do while loop instead. And I think I know how to do that without big problems.
Here is my code

```
using System;

 namespace MyFirstProgram
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Random random = new Random();
             bool playAgain = true;
             int min = 1;
             int max = 100;
             int guess;
             int number;
             int guesses;
             String response;

             while (playAgain)
             {
                 guess = 0;
                 guesses = 0;
                 response = "";
                 number = random.Next(min, max + 1);

                 while (guess != number)
                 {
                     //opening quote
                     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                     Console.WriteLine("gissa talet\nDu ska nu gissa ett tal mellan 1 
 ocn 100, så varsågod..\nskriv in ett tal");
                     guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                     Console.WriteLine("Guess: " + guess);

                     //when guess is over 100
                     if (guess > 100)
                     {
                          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                          Console.WriteLine("Du måste skriva in ett tal mellan 1 och 
 100!");
                     }
                     else
                     {

                         //if guess is to small
                         if (guess > number)
                         {
                             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                             Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för litet. gissa på ett 
 större tal");
                         }

                         //if guess is to large
                         else if (guess < number)
                         {
                             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                             Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för stort. gissa på ett 
 mindre tal.");
                         }

                         //when your guess is close but not right
                         if (Math.Abs(guess - number) <= 3)
                         {
                             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                             Console.WriteLine("Du är dock nära och det bränns");
                         }
                     }
                         guesses++;
                 }
                 //when you won
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                 Console.WriteLine("Grattis du gissa rätt,\n talet är" + " " + number);
                 Console.WriteLine("gissning" + " " + guesses);

                 //playagain command
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                 Console.WriteLine("vill du spela igen? (Ja/Nej): ");
                 response = Console.ReadLine();
                 response = response.ToUpper();

                 if (response == "Ja")
                 {
                     playAgain = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     playAgain = false;
                 }
             }
             //end quote
             Console.WriteLine("tack för att du spela");

             Console.ReadKey();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: is says that there is a build error and that it won´t run, visual studio says that it´s the Main in static void Main(string[] args) that is wrong but i can´t see why

Comment: The code seems ok. Maybe there is a misconfiguration in your project or solution.
Or maybe you have other files with errors. Than your compiler won't build your game

Comment: The code seems fine, since I'm able to run it. I left an answer with the reason why it doesn't restart the game

Comment: `response == "Ja"` can never be true, as you have `response = response.ToUpper();` (so if someone writes `"Ja"`, `response` will become `"JA"`)

Comment: Could the problem be that there are line breaks in your strings? Which makes it not able to compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have line breaks in your strings, which make your code unable to compile. In C#, you can't break strings like this:

```cs
// This does not compile
string str = "my string on
several lines";
```

I tagged involved lines with `/* here ---> */` comments below:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyFirstProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            bool playAgain = true;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 100;
            int guess;
            int number;
            int guesses;
            String response;

            while (playAgain)
            {
                guess = 0;
                guesses = 0;
                response = "";
                number = random.Next(min, max + 1);

                while (guess != number)
                {
                    //opening quote
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
/* here ---> */     Console.WriteLine("gissa talet\nDu ska nu gissa ett tal mellan 1 ocn 100, så varsågod..\nskriv in ett tal");
                    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess: " + guess);

                    //when guess is over 100
                    if (guess > 100)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
/* here ---> */         Console.WriteLine("Du måste skriva in ett tal mellan 1 och 100!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if guess is to small
                        if (guess > number)
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
/* here ---> */             Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för litet. gissa på ett större tal");
                        }
                        //if guess is to large
                        else if (guess < number)
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
/* here ---> */             Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för stort. gissa på ett mindre tal.");
                        }
                        //when your guess is close but not right
                        if (Math.Abs(guess - number) <= 3)
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine("Du är dock nära och det bränns");
                        }
                    }
                    guesses++;
                }
                //when you won
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Grattis du gissa rätt,\n talet är" + " " + number);
                Console.WriteLine("gissning" + " " + guesses);

                //playagain command
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("vill du spela igen? (Ja/Nej): ");
                response = Console.ReadLine();
                response = response.ToUpper();

                if (response == "JA")
                {
                    playAgain = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playAgain = false;
                }
            }
            //end quote
            Console.WriteLine("tack för att du spela");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could however write it with [verbatim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) string literal (`@"myText"`):

```cs
// This compiles
Console.WriteLine(@"gissa talet
Du ska nu gissa ett tal mellan 1 ocn 100, så varsågod..
skriv in ett tal");
```

---

Side note: if you guess the right number, you still enter the "*guess is close*" part (as `guess-number == 0` which is `<= 3`).

See red line in below screenshot:

[image: good guess]

Comment: i’ll look into it when i get back home from work. That other problem with ”guess is close” is a problem i had with my older code, and i think i know the problem.  Thank you

Comment: @Rafalon if you check the screenshot he send in the comments, you can see that the line break isn't the issue. The linebreak is added in SO

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't work is that you convert the response to upper case. However you don't check for the upper case version of the word.

So `if (response == "Ja")` should be if `(response == "JA")`

Comment: i just tried this and it still doesn´t work... can it be a problem with visual studio 2022 that makes it not work?

Comment: bacuase it´s weird, i tried it yesterday and it worked fine then

Comment: I also ran the code in Visual Studio 2022. So that can't be the problem. You might want to clean the solution and then build it again (Right click on the solution and click "Clean solution"). If that doesn't work. Can you send a screenshot of the error/message you see?

Comment: The clean solution did not work… how do i send screenshots on stack overflow?

Comment: You can either change your question, or upload it to imgur and send the URL here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rnNIRwM here is the link to Imgur.

Comment: Can you send another one, but with the error list open at the bottom?

Comment: I have run the code as modified by Kevin & it works for me too - the only problem I had was the newlines in the strings - if that was not down to cut&paste from the code snippet, that maybe your build error. If not please show the actual error.

Comment: I have taken parts for a other code into my original code, and when i did that yesterday it worked fine, and when i started up vs2022 this morning, it didn’t start. And i tried to fix it for over 1 houre without luck, that’s why i came here, because i don’t know what happend…

Comment: That is why I want to know what is in the error list. There should be some information what causes this issue.

Comment: We need to know the exact text of the error that is reported to be able to help you - just saying there is an error, then showing a screenshot that does not have the text of the error leaves us unable to help you. 
Generally, the error messages explain the error - read those errors carefully, if that does not help - then please post the error messages that are reported in the Error List window.

Comment: For the record, copy/pasting OP's code into [Online C# compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_csharp_compiler) worked just fine for me (except for that `"Ja"` vs `"JA"` part obviously) - had to remove some line breaks in strings though

Comment: for some reason it worked when i started a new project on vs2022. thanks so much for the effort and time to help :)

Comment: @KentKarlsson did you also end up changing the "Ja" with "JA" which caused the issue you asked?

Comment: yes i did change it but it didn´t change anything, i just made a new project and copy/paste in my code in the new project and it worked just fine for some odd reason... but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, usually when you compare `string` in C#, seek for ways that let you also provide `StringComparison`.

For example, if I want to check if a `string` is `Ja`, but without considering character case, I can write something like this:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "JA";

        if (input.Equals("Ja", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They're the same!");
        }
    }

// result: They're the same!
```

By the way, C# `Dictionary` also supports this.

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        
        dict.Add("Ja", "Peko");
        
        Console.WriteLine(dict["JA"]);
    }

// result: Peko
```

Comment: for some reason it worked when i started a new project on vs2022. thanks so much for the effort and time to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Besides your other problems you have a infinite loop hidden somewhere here...

```
    //if guess is to small
if (guess > number)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för litet. gissa på ett större tal");
}

//if guess is to large
else if (guess < number)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är för stort. gissa på ett mindre tal.");
}

//when your guess is close but not right
if (Math.Abs(guess - number) <= 3)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Du är dock nära och det bränns");
}
```

I am sure you can figure it out by yourself from here on!

Comment: Where is the hidden infinite loop?

Comment: Did you mean an infinite loop if user keeps entering wrong guesses? If not, then I can't see that loop you're talking about

Comment: Look at the last if. It says if the user Input minus the random number is less or equal 3. So if the guess is correct you would get 0 which indeed is less or equal 3 and enter the condition, which is not what you want. Edit: Just seen that other users also commented about this

Comment: While this shows a text that shouldn't be shown, it doesn't make the loop infinite, as `guess == number`, so we still leave the `while (guess != number)` loop

Comment: You are right, I explained it badly.

Comment: for some reason it worked when i started a new project on vs2022. thanks so much for the effort and time to help :)